# registering converter for property in BeanPropertyRowMapper

Tags: java, spring

I am using **org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper** to convert the results of a JDBC statement into a Bean, which works well.

I just want to **convert one value of the result into another value** before filling a special bean property.

I created a **PropertyEditor** and tried to register it via the **CustomEditorConfigurer** and a custom **PropertyEditorRegistrar**, but the **PropertyEditor** is not used when the BeanPropertyRowMapper fills the properties.

When the BeanWrapperImpl looks for PropertyEditors it does not find one because the customEditorsForPath is always empty.

How do I get my PropertyEditor registered for that one special property of my Bean when using the **BeanPropertyRowMapper**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need to extend `BeanPropertyRowMapper` and register your editors in overriden `initBeanWrapper()`.