# How to convert an Enum when using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [registering converter for property in BeanPropertyRowMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884439/registering-converter-for-property-in-beanpropertyrowmapper)

When calling DB2 using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, I receive the following exception:

Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'Gender' for property 'gender'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [Gender] for property 'gender': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

With that said, I have attempted to register a Gender Formatter, and GenderToString and StringToGender Converters.  Neither Formatter nor Converters appear to work.

btw, I'm using java-configuration with annotations as opposed to XML-configuration. So, I'm registering these using a custom class marked with the @Configuration annotation which extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.  Also, both of these work perfectly fine when going to and from the JSP and Controller.  Somehow, I feel like I'm missing something when Spring handles my DB2 query.

WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc // This replaces <mvc:annotation-driven />
@NoTrace
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private GenderFormatter genderFormatter;

    @Autowired
    private GenderToStringConverter genderToStringConverter;

    @Autowired
    private StringToGenderConverter stringToGenderConverter;

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(final FormatterRegistry registry) {

        registry.addFormatter(this.genderFormatter);
        registry.addConverter(this.genderToStringConverter);
        registry.addConverter(this.stringToGenderConverter);
    }
}
```

The DAO:

```
@Repository
public class PersonDAO {

    public Person retrieve(final int id) {

        final MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();

        paramSource.addValue("id", id);

        try {
            return this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                RETRIEVE_PRIMARY_INSURED,
                paramSource,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Person>(Person.class));
        } catch (final RuntimeException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("RuntimeException: ", e);
                    throw e;
        }
    }
}

public class Person {

private int id;
private Name name = new PersonName();
private Age age;
private Gender gender;

// getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I don't believe these formatters work with JdbcTemplate, just data from a Request to an object. Can you post the code for your RowMapper? That's where the conversion will need to take place.

Comment: technically speaking, I'm using BeanPropertyRowMapper -from what I understand, I wouldn't have to create a custom instance of RowMapper.  I could simply use the objects I already have (in this case Person), and Spring would make the conversions for me.  I believe this is where my problem occurs.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884439/registering-converter-for-property-in-beanpropertyrowmapper

Comment: @beny23 - thanks, I do think that was related.  Their solution seems to use PropertyEditors.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that with Spring 3, they were steering away from PropertyEditors in favor of Converters and Formatters?