# Add Converter to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've written an implementation of Converter. How do I register it so that BeanPropertyRowMapper will use it when called by jdbcTemplate?

I'm using Spring Boot without webmvc. So far I haven't used xml configuration, and would like to keep it that way. My application class is annotated with @SpringBootApplication

This is my converter class:

```
public class StringToDelegationScope implements Converter<String, DelegationScope>
{
    @Override
    public DelegationScope convert(String s)
    {
        return DelegationScope.valueOf(s.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

There is a solution from 2010 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884439/registering-converter-for-property-in-beanpropertyrowmapper) but it involves extending BeanPropertyRowMapper. That shouldn't be necessary. This is made clear in the [Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Spring-config). However, I can't follow what they are actually after.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [registering converter for property in BeanPropertyRowMapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884439/registering-converter-for-property-in-beanpropertyrowmapper)

Comment: Thanks @miensol for your reply. That should work, however I don't think it's necessary to extend BeanPropertyRowMapper. I've added a link above that indicates that it's possible by configuring a spring conversion service (Though I can't work out what they're after)